# Detect scrolling ended in Xamarin.Forms.Scrollview

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to customize a scroll view to meet my particular set of requirements, and what I would like to do it detect when the user stops scrolling or otherwise takes their finger off the screen. I have tried several methods of attaching event listeners but have yet to find one that will actually fire any events.

I need to make this work on android and iOS, and would be happy to do this in either cross platform or platform specific code.

If anyone can provide any guidance, I would be extremely grateful!

As a small side note, if anyone could explain why in my custom scrollview renderer doing `Touch += MyTouchHandler` doesn't allow my touch handler to be called, that would be enormously helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect it by implementing this event handler:
Assuming your list is called *Items*, then you need to add this code to your page.xaml.cs file:

```
    var listview = new ListView ();

    listview.ItemsSource = Items;
    listview.ItemAppearing += (sender, e) =>
    {
       if(isLoading || Items.Count == 0)
           return;

       //hit bottom!
       if(e.Item.ToString() == Items[Items.Count - 1])
       {
           LoadItems();
       } 
   }
```

You can check the full implementation details here: https://gist.github.com/jamesmontemagno/465ced24fc8a206dcaf3#file-loadmoreonbottom-cs

Answer (score 2):

```
 var scrollView = new ScrollView ();
    scrollView.scrolled+=OnScrolled

    private void OnScrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
    {
        MyScrollView scrollView = sender as MyScrollView;
        double scrollingSpace = scrollView.ContentSize.Height - scrollView.Height;

        if (scrollingSpace <= e.ScrollY) // Touched bottom
            // Do the things you want to do
     }
```